# RxSwift Tap Event not triggered

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, reactive

I'm implementing the mvvm using RxSwif.

Here is what happens:

- Validate Fields (write 7 characters in both textFields).
- Tap the login button.
- API is called which is fine.
- Tap the button again.
- API is not called.

I noticed that the "validObservable" changes every time that I write something in textFields which is fine.

ViewController:

```
    var viewModel: LoginViewModelType!
  let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
  @IBOutlet weak var dniTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var logInButton: UIButton!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    logInButton.rx
      .tap
      .bind(to: viewModel.inputs.logInButtonDidTap)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)


    dniTextField.rx
      .text
      .bind(to: viewModel.inputs.dniChanged)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    passwordTextField.rx
      .text
      .bind(to: viewModel.inputs.passwordChanged)
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)


    /*viewModel.outputs.isLoginButtonEnabled
      .drive(onNext: { [weak self] isEnabled in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.logInButton.isEnabled = isEnabled
      })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    */

    viewModel.outputs.logIn
      .drive(onNext: { [weak self] user in
        guard let `self` = self else { return }
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showMainController", sender: user)
      })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    viewModel = LoginViewModel()
  }
```

ViewModel:

```
    var inputs: LoginViewModelInputs { return self }
  var outputs: LoginViewModelOutputs { return self }

  // ---------------------
  // MARK: - Inputs
  // ---------------------
  var dniChanged: BehaviorRelay<String?>
  var passwordChanged: BehaviorRelay<String?>
  var logInButtonDidTap: PublishSubject<Void> = PublishSubject<Void>()


  // ---------------------
  // MARK: - Outpuds
  // ---------------------
  var logIn: Driver<User>
  var isLoginButtonEnabled: Driver<Bool>

  private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

  public init () {
    dniChanged = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: "")
    passwordChanged = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: "")

    let dniObservable = dniChanged.asDriver().filterNil().asObservable()
    let passwordObservable = passwordChanged.asDriver().filterNil().asObservable()

    let dniValidation = dniObservable.map { $0.count > 4 }
    let passwordValidation = passwordObservable.map { $0.count > 3 }

    let validObservable = Observable.combineLatest(dniValidation, passwordValidation) { return $0 && $1 }.filter { $0 }

    isLoginButtonEnabled = validObservable.asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())

    let loginSuccessObservable = Observable.combineLatest(dniObservable, passwordObservable, validObservable) { (dni, password, valid) -> LogInRequest in
      return LogInRequest(dni: dni, password: password)
    }

    logIn = logInButtonDidTap.withLatestFrom(loginSuccessObservable).flatMapLatest({ request -> Observable<User> in
      return API.shared.post(endpoint: EndPoints.Authorize, type: User.self, body: request)
    }).asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that .empty() is causing the observable to complete, and the subscription to be disposed of as a consequence.

I'd put some .debug() instructions to make sure what gets disposed and when.

Comment: Tried to use .never() instead of .empty() and still happen the error. Btw, .debug doesn't exists right?

Comment: It does, you can put .debug() or .debug("this will be printed on each event")

Comment: You are right. The event is disposed after first use. How can I avoid this? I changed empty for .just() but still disposing.

Comment: I'd try again using .never(), and try to figure out what's being completed and being disposed of first.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem because the button size is zero